# When is “de quel” used as opposed to a simple “quel”?

Tags: pronoms, prépositions, interrogative, pronoms-interrogatifs

When and why do we use “de” before “quel/quelle” in some sentences while not in others?

Answer (score 4):

You need *de* when you're saying "about/of which" rather than just "which."

*Quel livre voulez-vous ?* - Which book do you want?

*De quel livre parlez-vous ?* - Which book are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason we use *de* before other determiners (*la*, *un/une*, *quelques*, etc.).

> Marie achète *quelle/la/une* robe
>   Paul vient **de** *quelle/la/une* banlieue
>   Rémi parle **de** *quels/ces/quelques* individus

When we need a prepositional phrase with *de* to introduce a noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

**Quel (quelle/quels) permet de préciser sur quoi porte une question**

Quelle nourriture manges-tu ?

**De a de nombreux emplois dont au moins:**

- (1) en tant que préposition (provenance);
- (2) dans des constructions verbales;
- (3) pour introduire une appartenance;
- (4) pour préciser certains verbes (origine).

**Partout où on peut construire une phrase avec *de un nom commun*, on peut en faire une forme interrogative avec *de quel nom commun*.**

**De peut précéder quel (interrogatif), comme n'importe quelle préposition:**

- sur quel
- vers quel
- de quel

Pour savoir si la construction interrogative est valide, on peut la mettre à la forme affirmative:

Cet emploi est donc souvent:

- (1) soit une indication de provenance.
- (2) soit une forme verbale particulière (nombreuses): parler de, se soucier de, se moquer de, ...
- et les autres emplois de de

(1) Je viens de cette ville  => de quelle ville viens-je ?

(2) Il parle de ce film => de quel film parle-t-il ?

(3) C'est la maison de ma tante => de quelle personne est-ce la maison ?

(4) Cette cheminée est faite de marbre rose => de quel marbre est faite cette cheminée ?